# Setting random seed for cytoscape.js force-directed layout?

Tags: cytoscape.js

In cytoscape.js 2.0.0beta1, is it possible to get the arbor layout to produce a deterministic result?  I'd like to be able to do the equivalent of setting the random seed it uses to a fixed number.

My sample code is here:  http://www.strgen.org/~jmc/cs2/ppi1.html

If you reload it, you'll notice that the nodes can end up in very different layouts each time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think arbor provides an option for this, so I don't think this would be possible without significant revision to arbor itself first.